# MongoDB C# Driver -- Create Index

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am using the [MongoDB C# driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/admin_quick_tour/#create-an-index) to create an index

When my app starts up, it creates the index as below

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(new BsonDocument("code", 1), new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = true, Sparse = true });
```

My question is this: If the index already exists,  the index will not be re-created/indexed again, correct?

Comment: Should not create a new one as long as everything is the same... however it'd have been **REALLY** easy to just try it, create the index several times then list them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

As long as the parameters don't change (e.g `"code"` becomes `"Code"` or `Sparse` becomes `false`) the index will not be recreated and the operation will be a no-op.

Comment: so when is the best time for index creation when one is creating web api using DI containers and repository pattern? 
Maybe in constructors of repositories? But as repositories has lifetime of http requests it couse CreateIndex command to be send for every incoming request. Sure it would be no-op in 99% cases but still - isn't it a overkill?

Comment: @lukpep where is that web api is hosted. There's usually something alive throughout the service lifetime. Just call createIndex when the server starts once. The next time you start the server it will be a no-op.

Comment: I'm using ms azure. I was thinking to do it in initial configuration of my mongo module (where conventions are registered etc.) but I don't like idea that every time I crate new domain repository I have to remember to go to mongo configuration module and add indexes. I would be really convenient to register needed indexes in repository somehow. Maybe autofac could get all classes from assembly that implement some marker interface IMongoRepository and look for static array of idexes to register on initial startup?